# Sliding layout below status bar in Umano SlidingPanel

Tags: android, android-layout, android-sliding

I have implemented UmanoSlidingPanel using https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel . Everything is working fine except that my sliding panel when expanded, the sliding content (sliding_view) is going below the status bar. How can I avoid that?I tried removing

```
 <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

from styles.xml but that makes the status bar non-tranlucent for the main content also. Any way to fix this?

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/firstPanelDragArea"
    sothree:umanoPanelHeight="@dimen/bottom_panel_height"
    sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- SLIDING LAYOUT -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstPanelDragArea"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/sliding_view" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

styles.xml

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

**EDIT**

```
  public void onPanelSlide(View panel, float slideOffset) {
              if (slideOffset > 0.5 && !flagTransparent) {
                getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
                getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
                flagTransparent = true;
                Log.i(TAG, "onPanelSlide, offset " + slideOffset);
            } else if (slideOffset < 0.5 && flagTransparent){
                getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
                getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
                flagTransparent = false;
                Log.i(TAG, "onPanelSlide, offset " + slideOffset);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found another solution to the problem by making changes in onMeasure method of SlidingUpPanelLayout.java . Posting the code for future readers.Need to add 4 lines of code.

SlidingPanelLayout.java

```
 @Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    final int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    final int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    final int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    final int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    if (widthMode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Width must have an exact value or MATCH_PARENT");
    } else if (heightMode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Height must have an exact value or MATCH_PARENT");
    }

    final int childCount = getChildCount();

    if (childCount != 2) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Sliding up panel layout must have exactly 2 children!");
    }

    mMainView = getChildAt(0);
    mSlideableView = getChildAt(1);
    if (mDragView == null) {
        setDragView(mSlideableView);
    }

    // If the sliding panel is not visible, then put the whole view in the hidden state
    if (mSlideableView.getVisibility() != VISIBLE) {
        mSlideState = PanelState.HIDDEN;
    }

    int layoutHeight = heightSize - getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom();
    int layoutWidth = widthSize - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();

    // First pass. Measure based on child LayoutParams width/height.
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        final View child = getChildAt(i);
        final LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

        // We always measure the sliding panel in order to know it's height (needed for show panel)
        if (child.getVisibility() == GONE && i == 0) {
            continue;
        }

        int height = layoutHeight;
        int width = layoutWidth;
        if (child == mMainView) {
            if (!mOverlayContent && mSlideState != PanelState.HIDDEN) {
                height -= mPanelHeight;
            }

            width -= lp.leftMargin + lp.rightMargin;
        } else if (child == mSlideableView) {
            // The slideable view should be aware of its top margin.
            // See https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/issues/412.
 //                height -= lp.topMargin;.
 // START OF CODE CHANGES
            if (height < SCREEN_HEIGHT) {  //SCREEN_HEIGHT = 900
                height = height - MARGIN_BOTTOM; //MARGIN_BOTTOM = 8
            } else {
                height = height - getStatusBarHeight();
            }
 // END OF CODE CHANGES
        }


  public int getStatusBarHeight() {
    int result = 0;
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
    result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Have a look at the following [Gist](https://gist.github.com/aitorvs/770b1031ead1dce7147a) I created.

The file `sliding_up_activity.xml` could be the activity layout that will include your sliding up panel view.
It is in there where you should set `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` so that any children is inset properly not o fall behind the action bar or nav bar.

The file `sliding_view.xml` could be your sliding up view.

You should not need to do anything else in any of the panel callbacks.

You can safely remove the translucent style and the code inside the `onPanelSlide()`. This should result with a sliding panel properly inset such that never goes behind the status or nav bars.

Alternatively, if you don't have the same architecture, you could forget about the `sliding_up_activity.xml` and set `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in the `CoordinatorLayout` instead, in `sliding_view.xml`.

2) The second thing we were talking, is making the status bar translucent, letting the sliding up panel fall behind the status bar and then smoothly add padding to properly inset the contents.
For that, set `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"` or remove it from any possible parent your sliding up panel has.
Then in `onPanelSlide` you could do something like this

```
    if (slideOffset >= ANCHOR_POINT) {
        // adjust the span of the offset
        float offset = (slideOffset - ANCHOR_POINT) / (1 - ANCHOR_POINT);
        // the padding top will be the base original padding plus a percentage of the status
        // bar height
        float paddingTop = mSlidePanelBasePadding + offset * mStatusBarInset;
        // apply the padding to the header container
        mContainer.setPadding(0, (int) paddingTop, 0, 0);
    }
```

where:

- `mSlidePanelBasePadding` would be the initial padding of you sliding up panel
- `mStatusBarInset` would be the status bar height.

That should add padding to your slidingUp panel progressively when it gets past the anchor point.

You can get the status bar height like this:

```
public int getStatusBarHeight() {
    int result = 0;
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return result;
}
```

I hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in the parent layout. That should fix your problem.

Another solution I have implemented in the past is, in the activity that contains the slidingUpPanel, you can style it with a translucent status bar (API >= 19):

`<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>`

And then in `onPanelSlide` callback, you can modify the padding of your slidingUpPanel adding progressively until the panel is fully up. In that moment the amount of added extra padding should be the status bar dimensions.

Comment: I tried android:fitsSystemWindows="true" . It didn't work. And regarding the 2nd solution about adding padding, that I had tried before. It works but it doesn't give a smooth transition on expanding the panel.

Comment: Can you post your layout? I will post later how to do smooth padding  on a gist. Main thing is doing it past the anchor point and progressively using the slide offset percentage. It works like a charm that way.

Comment: I meant the layout files that includes the slidingUpPanelLayout.

Comment: Edited my question to add what I have tried in onPanelSlide. This makes status bar non translucent onPanelExpanded but on sliding panel downward ,sometimes the panel becomes expanded again. Not sure why.

Comment: <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item> make the status bar show a translucent in color only.