# Umano Android SlidingUpPanel isn't going under status bar

Tags: android, android-statusbar, slidingpanelayout

This is quite different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34725871/sliding-layout-below-status-bar-in-umano-slidingpanel), it's basically the opposite request, but I've tried to follow that solutions backwards anyway but I still doesn't have the slider going below my status bar. Here's a gif showing my results: 
[image]

Code below:
**activity_main.xml**

```
    <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    sothree:umanoPanelHeight="56dp"
    sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp">

    <!--MAIN CONTENT-->
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_mainactivity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout_mainactivity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
             />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager_mainactivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


<!--SLIDING LAYOUT-->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_panel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_mini_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mini_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class=".fragments.MiniLayoutFragment"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

So what can I do now? I've tried to put these lines inside my style.xml but they didn't work

```
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
```

Comment: did you try to remove this `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`?

Comment: @jerrol Yes but it didn't work

Comment: hmmm.. I tried your code too, but mine is working try to look at this, [The normal state of SlidingPanel](https://imgur.com/a/kpUq1) and the [Expanded State of SlidingPanel](https://imgur.com/a/BklqY)

Comment: Maybe the issue is inside my style.xml, how is yours?

Comment: `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus" tools:targetApi="kitkat">true</item>
</style>`

This is just only my style.