# How do I put AndroidSlidingUpPanel layout under my Appbar?

Tags: android

I have implemented the AndroidSlidingUpPanel library in my app, everything works but i want the sliding layout to slide until it goes under my appbar.

Thank you

[image: Current State of the app]

[image: Want is part to go under is appbar]

[Link to the Library](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34725871/sliding-layout-below-status-bar-in-umano-slidingpanel)

Comment: @xRed no, I am asking for appbar not status bar. thanks

Comment: Did you try to set the SlidingPanel `layout_gravity="top"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use toolbar instead of appbar, You will find examples in google easily.